# Правильное использование lock tables

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Есть такой код на php:

```
$var = $db->query('select from `table`'); // выбрали значения
doSomething($var); // обработали
$db->query('update `table`'); // записали обратно
```

Проблема в том, что иногда во время исполнения doSomething() скрипт запускается еще раз (к примеру, пользователь заходит на сайт), и doSomething() исполняется дважды с одними и теми же значениями. Есть идея использовать lock tables, но как это правильно сделать?

```
$db->query('lock tables `table`'); // заблокировали
$var = $db->query('select from `table`'); // выбрали значения
doSomething($var); // обработали
$db->query('update `table`'); // записали обратно
$db->query('unlock tables'); // разблокировали
```

Так?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А транзакции использовать не пробовали? Ваш подход очень напоминает ручную реализацию блокировок из транзакций

Comment: А как их правильно использовать в данной ситуации, если таблицы в MyISAM?

Comment: Про блокировки можно немного почитать [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/46542/) (если еще не читали), но больше другое интересует: а чем MyISAM так приглянулся? Может все-таки на InnoDB посмотреть?

И блокировка не спасет: все равно будет два выполнения с теми же данными, просто не одновременных. Поэтому лучше сделать по-другому: например, в сессию (или memcache) сохраняете запись о том, что `doSomething` выполняется и перед следующим выполнением проверяете этот флаг. Тогда лишние действия выполняться не будут. Если `doSomething` надо выполнять еще и потом, то флаг можно убрать когда будет над

Comment: MyISAM - сайт не мой, поэтому там все MyISAM.  
Проблема в том, чтобы блокировать чтение для всех пользователей, пока не обработан update текущего пользователя. Поэтому вопрос: до какого момента mySQL считает сессию открытой, до выполнения кода mysql_close() (или аналогичного)?